# dll targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86' when there is no x86

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I am attempting to create an installer using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I have an old project that builds. It is set to build x64 and I have even deleted the x86 options.

I added a Microsoft Installer project, however every time I try to build the installer project I get:
ERROR: File 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

However, the target platform is x64 and as I stated above, I have even tried removing all the x86 options leaving the only the x64 option in the Configuration Manager and yet it continues to insist that the target platform is x86.

How can I convince it to target x64 for real?